# webpack change import to require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm want to compile my nodeJS project with webpack. when it compiled every thing is correct but import changed to require and when I want to run index.js get error that must use import in ES module.

this is my webpack.config.js:

```
import path from "path";
import {fileURLToPath} from "url";
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import nodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";

export default {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        chunkFormat: "module"
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```

and this is my typescript file:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
fetch("http://example.com").then((data => console.log(data)));
```

when its get compiled:

```
const o = require("node-fetch");
```

I want to be:

```
import o from "node-fetch";
```

I want webpack don't change ES to commonJS and just optimize and minified my files.

Comment: Something you may have missed: Node 19 has Fetch built in now, so if you're staying up to do, you don't need `node-fetch` anymore.

Comment: Yes. I can use that but what about another libraries I can't import any library.

Comment: Not sure why you're use webpack at all if you just want to create a module bundle. Use [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Currently at the time of writing, outputting ESM with Webpack 5 is still experimental and must be [enabled using a special configuration option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experimentsoutputmodule).

To enable outputting your bundle as ESM you must add the following to your Webpack config:

```js
// webpack.config.js
export default {
 // ... other config
 experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
 },
 // ... other config
}
```